# Improving a question to get an answer

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I was looking for an answer. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533812/how-to-get-the-remaining-left-space-using-jquery) related to it, but it did not have a answer. I just edited it, put my code in it and it was rejected. May I know why? Is it necessary to ask it in a new question, why can't I edit it to get an answer?

[image]

Comment: Is it not self-explaining why you shouldn't edit someone else's question with your *own*?

Comment: @Pekka웃 : But by doing that , I along with that guy who asked the question gets an answer . So its good for that person too. and isn't it better if I help in getting an answer for a stackoverflow question , which was just left out without any answer

Comment: @yoyo How do you know that's what they wanted to ask?

Comment: There'd be way too much space for misunderstandings and changing of meaning if that were allowed. Note that you'd be changing the question already - from "how do I do this" to "does this code do what I want".

Comment: @Pekka웃 ok accpeted Sir ...

Comment: Also note that *"Is it a dependable code ??? Or You guys have a better solution ???"* is: 1. Not a good SO question; 2. An abuse of punctuation; and 3. Potentially discouraging for the people that would like to answer others' questions but don't identify as guys.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Now whats the reason for the downvote of this question , I had a doubt and i asked it here. Did i do any mistake . If you can explain . Thanks

Comment: On Meta, downvotes can mean disagreement - in this case, probably, that editing the question was the wrong thing to do. Don't worry, downvotes here do not reduce your reputation. All active Meta contributors have questions and answers with downvotes. It's a good thing you asked

Comment: @Pekka웃 : ohk thats something new I learnt today.  Thanks Sir.

Comment: @yoyo deinitely keep asking those when you are not sure :). Sometimes downvotes WILL mean a bad question on meta, but i truly dont believe this is your case

Comment: @Patrice : yea sure and Thanks Sir :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens quite often in another way: a (usually) new user posting his/her question as an *answer*. That's not acceptable either, and one of the auto-generated comments (from the Low Quality review queue) is also applicable in your situation:

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.